# SimpleGrantedAuthority cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring, maven

I want to add spring security to my project so I created a class to manage authentication:

```
public class MyAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private static final List<GrantedAuthority> AUTHORITIES
        = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

    static {
        AUTHORITIES.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        AUTHORITIES.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ANONYMOUS"));
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        if (auth.getName().equals(auth.getCredentials())) {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(auth.getName(),
                auth.getCredentials(), AUTHORITIES);
        }

        throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad Credentials");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {

        if ( authentication == null ) return false;
        return Authentication.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);

    }
}
```

The problem is that it can't resolve to `simplegranted` object giving me this error:

> The import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority cannot be resolved.

I think it's a dependency problem so here's my pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Spring3HibernateMaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>Spring3HibernateMaven</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description></description>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <!-- this is used to download jta-1.0.1B.jar dependency fo hibernate entity -->
    <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
      <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- spring security dependency -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- end spring security dependency -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>20030825.184428</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
      <version>20030825.183949</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
</project>
```

I am using spring version 3.0.2.RELEASE

Comment: (1) Use a modern version of Spring if possible; 4.2 is already in RC. (2) Spring Security has its own version, and you shouldn't use the same property for the Spring version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority` didn't exist in Spring Security 3.0.x.

It was added in Spring Security 3.1.0.

The stable version of Spring Security is up to 4.0.1 now... did you really intend to use 3.0.2?

Incidentally, Spring doesn't use a single version across all their products.  Spring Framework is up to 4.1.6.